# App to track daily life activity (to monitor personal enhancement)

Tags: android, fitness

## Summary

I want to have a protocol of what I eat, how much I sleep and when, how much exercise I do etc.

To do this I want to have an app for my android where I can insert all that data while it happens. The goal is to figure out which elements of my life I need to improve to achieve personal goals (be more focused / awake, how well I am getting stuff done etc.)

Its totally fine for me to pay for such an app. I don't mind where the data is stored, locally on the phone or in the cloud is both fine. I strongly prefer apps that have no ads.

I need two features: One for entering data and one for getting the data for statistics.

### Entering data

It should minimally allow me to create a kind of task that I have to name myself. Then I have to add new occurrences of that task, each with own details; like this:

1. Create task "eat"
2. Insert occurrence "breakfast 2015-03-03 - 2 cups of coffee, 1 slice of bread"
3. Insert occurrence "2nd breakfast 2015-03-03 - cheesebum and hot choc"
4. Insert occurrence "lunch - nut pastries, 1 cup of coffee, 1 energy cake"
5. and so on for all situations where I eat.

The more templates etc. the app has the better it would be. The less I have to think about it, the more likely am I to insert it all.

Ideally it should have a selection about "how I feel" or how productive I am so I can track that directly with it.

Bonus if it reminds me every two hours or so from 07.30 to 19.30 to insert the data.

### Retrieving data

I want to use that data to generate statistics about when I felt well (was productive, etc.) and then track back what I did before that to figure out what I need to do more to feel better more often.

At least the data need to be exportable to a raw data format that I can then use within an external application to create the statistics. Ideally, that function would be part of the app in the first place. I don't mind it if that statistics part is outside of the app (e.G. in a Webtool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [aTimeLogger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aloggers.atimeloggerapp)

I use aTimeLogger. It is an activity logging app that allows you both to track an activity and to enter its data manually. It comes with a set of default activities (eat, sleep, walk, etc...), and you have the ability to add custom ones.

**Entering data**

Here is an example for entering data:

[image]

You could specify whether the activity is currently in progress (running) so that it keeps timing it, or if the event has been paused or stopped. You could also add comments, and different intervals of the same event

**Retrieving data**

Through the "Reports" feature you have the choice to export the data from chosen events into either `CSV` or `HTML` formats

[image]

**Other features**

Other features include:

- It is free
- It comes with custom homescreen widgets for quick logging
- Ability to set goals
- Ability to organize activities in groups
- Ability to log simultaneous events
- Can be configured to automatically start and stop tracking using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)
- Provides statistics in forms of graphs and pie charts

Comment: I installed it and will now evaluate it. In two weeks or so I can tell if it did its job. At first it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Smarter Time](https://www.smartertime.com/) is what I need. **It can guess what you're doing based on the time and your location.**

Features:

- Room-level Location
- Learning Capabilities
- Apps and calls tracking
- Desktop Client
- Calendar Integration

You can have a secondary field you input the details of your activities (what am I eating now?) though my feeling is that there are apps better suited those details. I recommend KeepTrack or TrackThisForMe for a generic app tracking the details.

## My usage

First, I'm not in any affiliation with this app. I have spent a lot of time to search for an app tracking, and this app comes as a miracle to me. I feel that a true time tracking app should be intelligent enough to know what you're doing **without asking**, and this *combination of ideas* can do that.

I even took a screenshot back in the days I had sleep dysfunction. You can see how the ups and downs in my sleep time affect other activities. It's not that having accurate and detailed data isn't important, but the crucial thing in tracking your life is to have the fundamental understanding of what you actual do. I've spent a lot of time to finely choose the correct names for the names of my activities.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>*Led & fleeting*: a group of activities that basically hooks me into them, but not really increases my productivity, like Facebook or YouTube recommendations. They can lead me because they are so good at knowing my interest, but what I get is very fleeting.</sup>

The app use your home WiFi signal to guess your activities. One down side is that they don't allow real-time import/export except there is a strong demand for it.